# gruntfile.js - grunt.registerTask

Tags: javascript, task, gruntjs, runner

Not sure if I'm doing it right...

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json') ,
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                port: 8001 ,
                hostname: 'localhost' ,
                base: 'www-root/app/public' ,
                keepalive: true
            }
        }
    } ,
    jade: {
        files: {
            src: 'app/components/jade/index.jade' ,
            dest: 'app/public/index.html' 
        }
    } ,
    compass: {
        options: {
            config: 'config.rb'
        }
    } ,
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: '**/*.sass' ,
            tasks: ['sass'] ,
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        } ,
        jade: {
            files: 'app/components/**/*.jade' ,
            tasks: ['jade'] ,
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        }
    } 
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jade');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'jade', 'compass', 'watch']); 
}
```

Every time I run grunt, it only shows me the connect task and nothing else happens for example when I change my index.jade file... Is it a problem with the way I organized the tasks in order or should I add something that runs the tasks asynchronously?

Not sure what to do.. Thanks!

Comment: Can I know why it's down voted for no reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Grunt Connect Documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#keepalive)

> keepalive: Keep the server alive indefinitely. Note that if this option is enabled, any tasks specified after this task will never run.

So you're going to want to reorder the task list in your 'default' assignment:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jade', 'compass', 'connect']);
```

Or something of that sort. Hope that helps ;)